# big number represents a date

Tags: web-scraping, epoch, date-conversion

I was scraping kickstarter.com In the html (page source) there is strange code. For example for the following:
    https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1598272670/chip-the-worlds-first-9-computer?ref=category_most_backed&ref=discovery

```
launched_at&quot;:1431011162
```

Is there a way to convert this number "1431011162" a date? is there a way to translate it to ISO date format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a UNIX epoch timestamp - the number of seconds since midnight, 1 Jan 1970. This (1431011162) converts to (GMT) Thursday, 7 May 2015 3:06:02 PM.

https://www.epochconverter.com/ is a handy converter.